# SQLAlchemy operator for PostgreSQL's aggregate (every)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

PostreSQL features the [`every()` aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html), which filters groups by running a predicate on all group rows.

For example, for the following table:

```
 star_name | star_type | landed_upon
-----------+-----------+-------------
 Mars      | Planet    | t
 Venus     | Planet    | t
 Rhea      | Moons     | f
 Titan     | Moons     | t
```

This `every()` query:

```
SELECT star_type, max(star_name) example, COUNT(*)
    FROM stars
    GROUP BY star_type
    HAVING every (landed_upon = true);
```

Returns the `Planet` group but not the `Moons` group, because `Rhea` does not satisfy the `landed_upon` predicate within the `Moons` group:

```
 star_type | example | count
-----------+---------+-------
 Planet    | Venus   |     2
(1 row)
```

Is there an equivalent SQLAlchemy operator for PostgreSQL `every()`?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but `.having(func.every(Star.landed_upon))` should work.

Comment: @Marth Excellent, it works. Care to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `func` object to generate SQL functions.

```
.having(func.every(Star.landed_upon))
```

will generate

```
HAVING EVERY(stars.landed_upon)
```